# What is the recommended SharePoint site to use for External Site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, publishing-site, site-template, sharepoint-on-prem

We are planning to design an external site. I want to know what is the recommended site template to use? Is it the Publishing Site?

For example, Check this site (http://glenview.il.us/Pages/Default.aspx).

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

**As a short answer :** Yes it's SharePoint publishing site.

**A SharePoint publishing site** is a site that’s built using a publishing site template.

[image]

**A SharePoint publishing site** is a site where authoring and publishing are more structured and where content management processes are enforced. Publishing sites are typically used to create enterprise intranets, communication portals, and public websites.

**Generally** , when you try to select a specific template for your site 
 you should know the functionality and main features of this template and match it with your requirements .So for **Publishing template** I tried to answer this questions that match with internet site requirements as the following :

1. What is the use of Publishing portal template?

   - Publishing portal template Use for an Internet site or a large intranet portal site.
2. What's the main features of Publishing portal template?

   - You can use distinctive branding to customize this site.
   - Create custom Master Page , Page Layout based on your requirements.

[image]

- By default, this site collection template enables content approval workflows for a more formal and controlled publishing process.
- It also lets you grant permissions to anonymous users to view only content pages.
- Anonymous users cannot view SharePoint Server 2013 administrative pages, such as the Site Settings page.

For more details check

- [Overview of publishing to Internet, intranet, and extranet sites in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635881.aspx)
- [Build a SharePoint publishing site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Build-a-SharePoint-publishing-site-60b4402c-894a-452c-9df9-d6546d5172b6)